# Relativistic force parallel to momentum

Tags: special-relativity

I'm going through Landau's book on Classical Field Theory (i.e. vol 2), and I'm a bit stuck on the part about relativistic force.  For the case where the force is perpendicular to the momentum, he gives
$$\frac{d\textbf{p}}{dt}=\frac{m}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}}\frac{d\textbf{v}}{dt}$$
which I think is because $v^2$ remains constant.  However, for the case where the force is parallel, he gives it as
$$\frac{d\textbf{p}}{dt}=\frac{m}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}}+\frac{d\textbf{v}}{dt}$$
Is there a typo in this or am I missing something deeper?  Setting aside that it seems to add a scalar to a vector, my own calculations (and what I can find online) give it as $F=\gamma^3ma$.  Where is the discrepancy?

Comment: The expression with the plus sign has inconsistent units.

Comment: This is definitely just a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is weird. As far as I see, Landau & Lifshitz do not make use of this relationship, except mentioning that "the ratio of force and acceleration is different in the two cases"
which surely is true.

Your own calculation is correct:

When only the magnitude $v$ of $\mathbf{v}$ depends on time then the normalized velocity $\hat{\mathbf{v}}=\mathbf{v}/v$ is constant and therefore
$$
\frac{d\mathbf{v}}{dt}=\hat{\mathbf{v}}\,\dot v=\frac{\mathbf{v}}{v}\dot v\,,
$$
and
\begin{align}
\frac{d\mathbf{p}}{dt}&=m\hat{\mathbf{v}}\frac{d}{dt}\frac{v}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}}=-\frac{1}{2}m\hat{\mathbf{v}}\,\frac{v\,(-2v\dot v/c^2)}{\Big(1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}\Big)^{3/2}}+m\hat{\mathbf{v}}\frac{\dot v}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}}\\
&=
m\mathbf{v}\gamma^3\frac{v\dot v}{c^2}+m\frac{d\mathbf{v}}{dt}\gamma\\
&=m\frac{d\mathbf{v}}{dt}\gamma^3\frac{v^2}{c^2}+m\frac{d\mathbf{v}}{dt}\gamma\,.
\end{align}
From
$$
\gamma^2\frac{v^2}{c^2}+1=\frac{v^2/c^2+1-v^2/c^2}{1-v^2/c^2}=\gamma^2
$$
it follows that
$$
\boxed{\quad\frac{d\mathbf{p}}{dt}=m \frac{d\mathbf{v}}{dt}\gamma^3\quad}
$$
as [expected](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_in_special_relativity#Transverse_and_longitudinal_mass).